# Square API: Null order id for Transaction

Tags: java, square

I'm using Square for a restaurant and trying to get a count of how many chicken wings sold for a day.  We sell it in 5pc, 10pc, 20pc orders so I was hoping to pull the quantities for each so I could sum it up.

I'm using Java and tried the TransactionsApi to retrieve transactions but these all return an order_id of null.

Is there something I'm missing or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`order_id` will only be supplied if you supply it while calling the `Charge` endpoint. You would need to actually use the `CreateOrder` endpoint, and supply the items, and then supply the `order_id` to the `Charge` endpoint. See https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/orders-api-overview for more information.

Currently the only way to see itemization when using the POS application for in-person payments, is to use the V1 `Payments` API. See https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/orders-api-overview to review the endpoints.